# Postgres schemas are common in all databases

Tags: postgresql, patroni

I created a postgres cluster with patroni. The schemas are common in all the databases. Any table created in a schema of one database, appears also in the same schema of all other databases.
Creating a new schema in one database, creates the same schema in all other databases.
Postgres version is 12.15 running on Oracle Linux 8.
Is this a setting that I can turn off in order to separate the databases?
I'm creating schemas and databases using pgAdmin4 7.1, I don't have experience with psql

The setup instructions I followed came from here https://www.techsupportpk.com/2020/02/how-to-create-highly-available-postgresql-cluster-centos-rhel-8.html
I re-installed from scratch and the behavior is the same

Comment: I presume this is an issue with Patroni as tables and schemas are not shared between databases.  It could also be a terminology issue, if you could include some code showing the issue it would be much easier to help.  I'd encourage you to learn how to use psql as well, it's a great tool!

Comment: Finally found the mistake. It was in the pgbouncer configuration. When connected directly to postgres things were working properly. When connecting through the pgbouncer all databases where somehow merged to one.

Answer (score 1):

Patroni uses PostgreSQL streaming replication, which keeps the standby server a faithful physical copy of the primary. So there is no way to avoid that if you create a table in a certain schema on the primary, that table will also be created in the same schema on the standby.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in my pgbouncer configuration. In the databases section I had

```
* = host=192.168.10.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres
```

The correct configuration must have a different entry for each database, without the wildcard

```
postgres = host=192.168.10.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres
analytics = host=192.168.10.1 port=5432 dbname=analytics
```